# MSVC compiler intrinsic for launching a software interrupt

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, x86-64, intrinsics

Is there a compiler intrinsic for x86 software interrupt instructions other than 0x2C in MSVC2017 (x64)?

The intrinsic for [`int 0x2C`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INTn:INTO:INT3:INT1.html) is [`__int2c()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/int2c?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Looks like no, unless they have different names.  What does `int 0x2c` do on Windows?  Is that how a way to make raw 32-bit system calls?

Comment: @PeterCordes :On windows, it acts as an assertion (assertion failure) break point when debugging.

Comment: @PhantomR : Are you still trying to write a bootloader/kernel? Are you trying to calla BIOS interrupt?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am still trying, yes, but I'm not trying to call a BIOS interrupt as I know they're no longer available :). I want to test some interrupts I am going to write.